# No such file tsconfig.app.json when using docker to set up dev environment on Windows 10

Tags: windows, angular, docker, docker-compose

I am having a problem with using Docker to provide a development environment for Angular 5 on Windows 10.

Here's my ng version info:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 6.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

To try and find the solution to my problem, I used the Angular CLI (latest version) to create a new project, docker-test using:

```
ng new docker-test
```

I then cd'd into docker-test and added a dockerfile as shown below:

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN ["npm", "install"]
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 4200/tcp
EXPOSE 49153/tcp
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If I run 'ng serve' from Powershell, the app is served without a problem.

However, when trying to use Docker, I hit a problem.

Having removed all images and containers using:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

I am able to successfully build the image using:

```
docker build -t docker-test -f dockerfile .
```

and can 'docker run' successfully using:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 4200:4200 -p 49153:49153 docker-test:latest
```

However, if I attempt to use volumes to allow live updates using the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 4200:4200 -p 49153:49153 -v ${pwd}/src:/app/src docker-test
```

I get the following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/src/tsconfig.app.json'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/src/tsconfig.app.json'
at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:948:11)
at AngularCompilerPlugin._setupOptions (/app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:78:16)
at new AngularCompilerPlugin (/app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:43:14)
at _createAotPlugin (/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:77:16)
at Object.getNonAotConfig (/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:100:19)
at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:41:37)
at Class.run (/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:71:98)
at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:123:26)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! docker-test@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 500`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the docker-test@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-12T19_50_23_145Z-debug.log
```

and I can't work out what the problem is.
The file is on the host:

[image]

I get the same error if I use the following docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web: # name of the service
  build: ./ # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
  ports:
     - "4200:80"
     - "49153:49153"
  volumes:
     - '${pwd}/src:/app/src'
```

Any guidance on the issue or how to debug would be very gratefully received.